# Python - while all list elements result in true for .isalpha issue

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, element

I have used the following code to return a list as soon as an `element.isalpha()` becomes `False`:

```
  for element in initialList:
    if element.isalpha() == True:
      newList.append(element)
  return newList
```

`initialList` is a predefined list that contains random mixed letters/numbers for testing purposes, and of course `newList` is the return as soon as `element.isalpha()` becomes `False`

However, I have to use a `while` loop as well as a `break` statement to achieve this. How could I go by doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need a `break` statement but a `while` statement is not really helpful here.  Consider:

```
def f(initialList):
    newList=[]
    for element in initialList:
        if not element.isalpha():
            break
        newList.append(element)
    return newList
```

For example:

```
>>> f(['a', 'b', '!', 'c'])
['a', 'b']
```

#### Alternative (if you must use `while`)

```
def g(initialList):
    newList=[]
    i = 0
    while i < len(initialList):
        if not initialList[i].isalpha():
            break
        newList.append(initialList[i])
        i+=1
    return newList
```

Comment: The instructions I've been given specify a while loop. I'm not sure why, but it's probably to test me and I really have no idea how to implement the loop.

Comment: That works perfectly. Do you have any advice for line 5 of your while loop distinguishing between using `not` vs `== False`? I have not yet learned to properly use `not` and so I modified it to `if initialList[i].isalpha() == False:`

Comment: ``` == False``` is not technically wrong, but it is very "unpythonic."

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `all` to do it, the following code:

```
>>> li = ['a', 'b']
>>> all(e.isalpha() for e in li)
True
>>> li = ['a', 'b', '!']
>>> all(e.isalpha() for e in li)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop, just use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) -- this is exactly what it was made for. `f = lambda initial_list: filter(str.isalpha, initial_list)`